# Regex that match a pattern of word at the end of string?

Tags: php, regex

What could be the regex that match a pattern of word at the end of string? 
For example the following should match "qwerty [numeric][alpha]":

```
"blah blah qwerty 8z"
"blahh blahh qwerty 4vx"
```

**but not:**

```
"blah blah qwerty 8"
"blahh blahh qwerty 4"
```

Comment: @rock321987 why? Surely we're here to help :-) Glad tatskie got an answer that helped him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$re = "/(\\w+\\s+\\d+\\w+)$/m"; 
$str = "blah blah qwerty 8z\nblahh blahh qwerty 4vx"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rP9mT9/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/^.+(\d+[a-z]+)$/', 'blah blah qwerty 8z', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you mind explaining it a bit more? This helps ensure high quality answers across SO rather than just code snippets. Thanks!

Comment: [a-zA-Z] instead of [a-z] could be equivalent to the answer above?

Comment: @tatskie it's equal with `'/^.+(\d+[a-z]+)$/i'` **i**  is a modifier (modifies the search to be case-insensitive). See an example [here](https://eval.in/561941).